# Closures and deletions shouldn't automatically apply to edited questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

When users with relevant privileges decide to close or delete a question, they base their opinion on certain wording. When that wording is changed, it essentially becomes a different question, and the basis for that decision may no longer be present. It's especially problematic with [deleted questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/62584/what-prevents-a-would-be-dictator-from-ignoring-the-institutions-and-ruling-as-h?noredirect=1#comment249738_62584).

Once it's done, there is virtually no way to bring it back, even after editing, because you can't write a comment, mention other users, and ask them to vote to undelete.

I believe edited questions shouldn't be closed or deleted automatically just because their "ancestors" were. You may suggest that a question's author may edit their question repeatedly not in a meaningful way just to keep it open, but here's what I propose to prevent the abuse.

If the author of a question once or twice edits a closed or deleted question, but the same moderation decision is reconfirmed, then it would make sense to automatically apply the moderation decision made with respect to its earlier version to a newer one if the question was again edited by the creator of the question (but not if someone else edited it).

Comment: There is no such thing as “automatic closure” and automatic deletion is unlikely to happen to recently edited posts (as it only applies to older questions and questions which haven’t been edited in 9 days). So it’s unclear what you’re asking. Are you suggesting that we allow users to unilaterally reverse moderation decisions?

Comment: @Laurel If a closed or deleted question is edited, it should not be closed or deleted. Moderation decisions against some flawed questions cannot be applied to other questions (once it's edited, it in essence becomes a different question and may not contain the issues that served as the basis for a moderation decision)

Comment: Sergey, once you have edited the question, it should definitely not be automatically reopened - it may still fail to meet standards (we see this a lot) - the onus should be on the uathor to improve it enough that it deserves reopening

Comment: @RoryAlsop It may – or it may not. We don't know. You first consider a question, then make a judgment. There shouldn't be such a thing as "deserving a reopening". Every question deserves to be open unless it's been ruled otherwise. Once it's edited, it's a different question. It shouldn't automatically inherit the moderation decision made against its earlier version. We don't know whether it still contains any flaws or not. There should be the presumption of adherence, as the presumption of innocence in a court of law

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - If a question is deleted, there was a reason, most questions that can be improved by editing are only closed.  I don't often see questions, that can be salvaged, that are deleted by the community.  Questions are not "automatically" deleted until after a certain point of inactivity by the community user. What you proposed still will leave the community to a ton of abuse from users, who have their question deleted for a very specific reason, so questions in my opinion should never be undeleted or opened automatically.  The first edit to a question nominates it to be reopened.

Comment: *Furthermore, a flag to a moderator, can often get a question that had been deleted restored if the reason for it's deletion has been addressed.*

Answer (score 7):

> Once it's done, there is virtually no way to bring it back, even after editing, because you can't write a comment, mention other users, and ask them to vote to undelete.

The correct way here is to either post on the site's meta, drop by the site's chatroom, or, in case it was deleted by a diamond moderator, to use a custom flag asking for them to take a look and undelete it, as the community can't override a moderator's delete vote.

Once that is done, people can also start voting to reopen your post.

Having just any edit invalidate already cast close or delete votes without human oversight  is a bad idea: There just isn't a system that you could build that would recognize whether your edit fixed the problems with your post or whether you made it worse by vandalizing it. Besides, users can provide you with further feedback or edits that could make your post even better, something such a system would be hard-pressed to do.

Votes are already 'reversible', just not automatically. And we should probably keep it that way.

Answer (score 6):

When a post is closed because it needs improvement, either through community votes, or a moderator vote, the expectation is that the OP will edit it to make those improvements, at which point it can start getting reopen votes, either through the queues or through individuals visiting the question. The votes made to close it do not have any further effect, so I am unsure what you are getting at in your question. If it has been deleted by a mod, it is worth letting them know it has been edited so they can review, and if it meets requirements it can be reopened.

There is no concept of being closed or deleted because previous versions were closed.

Comment: Why did my question remain deleted after I edited it? The moderation decision was made against an earlier version, i.e. another question

Comment: No, that isn't how it works. Once you have edited, your best bet is to let a mod know (if they closed/deleted it) and they can see whether it meets requirements to be reopened.

Comment: Well, I didn't post it to find out how it works. I'm here to propose an amendment to the rules

Comment: @Sergey If you don't know how a system works, then proposing an amendment to it is a unilaterally bad idea.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - Your proposal opens the community to having to handle the same problematic contribution multiple times.  It is extremely easy to get a question undeleted, if the reason it was deleted, has actually been addressed by simply flagging a moderator.