# Require close voters to continually interact with questions they voted to close

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, vote-to-close

People who vote to close a question should be responsible for being active with the question poster. Meaning that if you vote to close the ownus is on you, the voter, to see the changes that you have requested, and work with the questionee.

No more drive by votes, no more vote and move on. The deal is, if you vote to close it, you share in the responsibilities.

Here is an example.

Sally asks a question which gets a close vote with reason by Billy, Frank and Anne.

Meanwhile Billy, Frank and Anne must now comment on the question again, they are attached to the question. Which means their acount is temporary attached to that question.

If Billy, Frank and Anne retract their votes then the question is open. However, if a time window is passed, the three must spend reputation to keep their close vote.

If Frank, Billy, and Anne are going to take the time to close, a question, it is assumed they have time to review it.

Comment: What? This feature request is extremely difficult to understand

Comment: "*[Question asker] then edits the question, [...] [Close voters] must now comment on the question again,*" I can only assume that you've not seen that many close votes. Because this is complete nonsense. A very large amount of questions get edited after closure and there is *no* attempt made to address the close reason. The edit might just fix spelling or add a few commas in the text. Forcing 3-5 people to go back and comment to the effect of "Read the close reason" 1. wastes everybody's time 2. may be off-putting to the question author.

Comment: "*If Frank, Billy, and Anne are going to take the time to close, a question, it is assumed they have time to review it.*" 1. No it's not. 2. No, there is no rational way to assume that. I may CV a question because I had 5 minutes to spare *now*. That doesn't mean I have 5 minutes to spare *later*. What if the edit comes when I'm asleep? Or maybe I'm in the hospital? Maybe I'm just off on vacation the next day? The close/reopen process doesn't happen in the span of 30 minutes. It might be hours or days before OP does anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closures and deletions shouldn't automatically apply to edited questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361137/closures-and-deletions-shouldnt-automatically-apply-to-edited-questions)

Comment: I would be happy to discuss this suggestion at the SO contributor pay review meetings.

Comment: “People who vote to close a question should be responsible for being active with the question poster.” - This is unrealistic. I cast dozens of close votes a day.  You expect volunteers to interact with dozens of users continuously through the comment section.  You do understand the comment section is absolutely horrible to deal with?  Nope, if this was implemented, I would just flag for moderator attention.  I don’t have the time to deal with dozens users daily who didn’t even submit a clear concise question.

Comment: From reading and interacting with a few of such posts mostly on MSO, I noticed a common thing present in nearly all of them in this case encompassed in "must spend reputation to keep their close vote". Nearly every post like that wants to *punish* those who do curation, and something tells me this is the real reasoning goal of the proposals instead of actually improving the close vote system. @Ben, I hope you realize that the only thing this will result in is just well-meaning people being scared off of closing off-topic, duplicate, or unclear questions.

Comment: Why would you essentially roll back spelling corrections by Robert? "ownus" is misspelled, and "temporary" should be an adverb instead of an adjective.

Comment: This is essentially the [same thing you posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338747/new-procedures-for-mitigating-closer-hostilities) a few years ago. Yet it doesn't address any of the feedback you got then. Why not? You want others to respond to issues yet don't do the same. Seems like a one way street

Answer (score 19):

First of all, this proposal is extremely difficult to understand, since it's not very clear exactly what you are requesting. Closing a question doesn't stop it from being seen on the main page, by the way.

It seems like you want it so that when OP edits the question, it's immediately reopened until people reclose it. This is an extremely bad idea for various reasons, including but not limited to abuse, new users "fixing" questions without fully addressing all of the community-specific reasons, etc.

First of all, the original users who closed a question don't have to be the ones to reopen it. Second of all, questions that are closed will not get hidden from the front page. Third of all, there is a review queue specifically to reopen closed questions that have probably been fixed.

Also, if a user posts a totally off-topic question because they didn't read the scope or help center, it isn't the close voters' responsibility to fix the question and guide them through the whole process; people are busy, and not everyone has time for that. People are given the privilege to vote to close because they are trusted with identifying what's off-topic, not because they are expected to undertake the responsibility to fix questions that are out of scope, especially if they are blatantly and unsalvageably so. Some users will be there to help users with their experience or available free time, and again, other people can reopen the question later.